# Why does the mean differ using summarySEwithin?

Tags: r

When I use summarySEwithin.R the mean it produces is different to the means I have calculated through SPSS and other R scripts (aggregate).

Why? Can I stop this and just get the mean?

I have a mixed data set (routinefailure.NS), with one between-subject factor (Condition: None and Static), and one within-subject factor (Group: routine and failure).

Does summarySEwithin normalise the mean? Can I use the mean from summarySE and the SE and CI from summarySEwithin?

Here is what my dataset looks like:

```
head(routinefailure.NS)
subj   Group Condition Class ClassRT  CPA CPART Dive DiveRT SAGAT ATWIT
300 routine      None  0.66   10.41 0.56 30.00 0.80   5.90  0.64  6.31
301 routine      None  0.90   19.54 0.32 28.46 0.86   5.42  0.65  5.47
302 routine      None  0.97   32.14 0.48 23.76 0.94   6.02  0.77  3.89
303 routine      None  0.93   23.73 0.33 35.32 0.90   5.57  0.45  5.72
304 routine      None  0.82   14.37 0.29  6.84 0.88   5.70  0.62  6.19
```

Here is what I did

> summarySE(routinefailure.NS, measurevar = "Class", groupvars = c("Condition", "Group"), na.rm = TRUE)

```
Condition   Group  N     Class         sd          se         ci
None       failure 30 0.8513333 0.17702003 0.032319288 0.06610037
None       routine 30 0.8230000 0.16071285 0.029342018 0.06001117
Static     failure 30 0.8440000 0.14194705 0.025915867 0.05300390
Static     routine 30 0.9253333 0.05090446 0.009293841 0.01900804
```

> summarySEwithin(routinefailure.NS, measurevar = "Class", betweenvars = "Condition", withinvars = "Group", idvar = "subj", na.rm = TRUE, conf.interval = 0.95)

```
Condition   Group  N     Class         sd         se         ci
None       failure 30 0.8750833 0.06200899 0.01132124 0.02315454
None       routine 30 0.8467500 0.06200899 0.01132124 0.02315454
Static     failure 30 0.8202500 0.09081496 0.01658047 0.03391086
Static     routine 30 0.9015833 0.09081496 0.01658047 0.03391086
```

I am not that good with R, but have managed until now. Any comment would be much appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you're using some non-standard packages. What package are `summarySE()` and `summarySEwithin()` in?

Comment: You can check both the code in both function by typing `summarySE` and `summarySEwithin` on the R console.  The `summarySE` is using the `ddply` to get the mean.  While with `summarySEwithin` it creates a `normDatawithin` and then calls `summarySE` on that.

Comment: Hi Gregor. Sorry meant to say it is in the Rmisc package

Comment: Thanks akrun. I didn't know you could just type in the function and see what it is. I did that and can see what you are saying. I am thinking there must be some statistical reason why summarySEwithin uses normDatawithin. That is great for the errors (SE and CI) but not so much for the mean I think. Might have to run summarySE for the mean and summarySEwithin for the within-subjects confidence intervals and SE values (which are much smaller).

Comment: The functions in Rmisc package uses plyr and don't provide the un-normed or raw means. I recently had to deal with this problem to and rewrote the functions so that they use data.table instead. If you need to use the summarySEwithin function in the future, here it is (summarySEwithin2 computes both the raw and normed means): https://gist.github.com/hauselin/a83b6d2f05b0c90c0428017455f73744#file-summarysewithin2-r

Comment: Hey hsl. The summarySEwithin2 script is great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @hsl, what is the difference between un-normed and normed value?

Comment: Check out this paper and link, @Chloe. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Richard-Morey/publication/49619437_Confidence_Intervals_from_Normalized_Data_A_correction_to_Cousineau_2005/links/0912f50f1968c611aa000000/Confidence-Intervals-from-Normalized-Data-A-correction-to-Cousineau-2005.pdf https://www.cogsci.nl/blog/tutorials/156-an-easy-way-to-create-graphs-with-within-subject-error-bars